# Script Returning �

Tags: 2013, javascript, alert

I use a lot of JavaScript in SharePoint, but today I came across a problem that I do not understand. Every time I use accents in a script such as in an alert, it returns the following strange symbol: �.

[image]

Only I'm using jQuery and the mask as libraries. My library does not have anything if I put an alert ('hi') it returns the 'í' with symbol �.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know [this article](http://www.tuxlanding.net/how-to-display-the-accented-characters-in-javascript/) is a bit old, but it might help. Replace your accented character with its octal  value.

```
Alt-m   \355   ED   U+00ED   &iacute;   í  small i, acute accent
```

Else, please try to use UTF8. Add the following in `<script type=... charset= ...>` :

```
charset="utf-8"
```

([source StackOverflow.SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088834/issues-with-the-accented-characters))

Comment: I know this functionality, it's called ASCII table, but I can not use because it is dynamic, the user enters the warning, then have no way to use the ASCII table.

And already used the charset, but it did not work.

Comment: the alert displays the ASCII characters 

Example: h&iacute;